# File Streaming Load Balancing?

Tags: file, static, streaming, load-balancing

I have a high-traffic website ( about 0.5 - 1.5 TB / day ) which offers drive-by downloads. It's currently streaming the files from the external source thru my servers and to the users. Actually I use roundrobin to distribute the load, however it fails me due to varying internet connection speed of my users and the number of connections they are downloading with ( some people download with one connection, some use download managers and download with 8 , for example ).

Is there any good solution to achieve better efficiency? Maybe I am able somehow to determine my user's internet connection speed and use it to do some math-based load balancing?

Thanks!